# Node.js Passing data from serverside to clientside

Tags: node.js

I had created a database connection and fetched the data from db on serverside. How can i pass my data from serverside to client side javascript in node.js. please help me out i had read many google searchs but didn't find any helpful stuff.
I'm using Emitter for my events. Now it is working on serverside my i can't able to pass the data to client side.

this is my code:

```
var dbrows;

// Connecting to Database.
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : ''
});
var  DBName   = 'use ChatDB';

connection.connect();

connection.query(DBName);

connection.query('SELECT * from chat', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  dbrows = rows;

});

connection.end();

// Event Emitter emits out pre-defined events.

var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var Emitter = new EventEmitter();
Emitter.on('ChatUsers', function () {
    console.log(dbrows);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node. js how can i pass my data to client side script from server side script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386843/node-js-how-can-i-pass-my-data-to-client-side-script-from-server-side-script)

Comment: if u want to push data to client. it is better to check socket.io. Or if u want to pull data from client. REST is more appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use `Emitter`, i suggest you to use a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) library like `socket.io`. It is simple to use. For your code, you can write something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('sendUsers', function (data) {
    connection.connect();

    connection.query(DBName);

    connection.query('SELECT * from chat', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;

      socket.emit('sendUsers', rows);

    });
    connection.end();

  });
});
```

and on client side:

```
socket.on('sendUsers', function(data){
    console.log(data); // here you have your db records.
});
```

More info and examples here:

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Thank you sou much for your answer! But on connection event i'm making connection of users. Is there any event in io.socket to do the above thing? and i also need to ask that in io.socket the events are predefined (i.e socket i.o provide the list of events for particular tasks e.g for making connection there is 'connection', for messages there is 'msg', for disconnecting there is 'disconnect')or we have advantage to make our own events?

Comment: @FaDi what do you mean by `connection of users`? can you explain this?

Comment: @ Alix I have made the database of users and i have to display a log of users by clicking particular user the user will add in chat. so i had made a connection to database and users are fetched in serverside but as i mentioned that i have to display the users on by browser so i have to pass the fetched user from server to client side. So the problem is that i can't able to pass the fetched data to client side. So the problem is that how can i pass the server side fetched data to client side?

Comment: @ Alix I had done the same as u said but it is not passing the data to client side :-(

Comment: connection of user means... Users are connecting/joining the chat

Answer (score 0):

here is the server side code:

```
// This file is required by app.js. It sets up event listeners
// for the two main URL endpoints of the application - /create and /chat/:id
// and listens for socket.io messages.

// Use the gravatar module, to turn email addresses into avatar images:

var gravatar = require('gravatar');

// Export a function, so that we can pass 
// the app and io instances from the app.js file:

module.exports = function(app,io){

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // Render views/home.html
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/create', function(req,res){

    // Generate unique id for the room
    var id = Math.round((Math.random() * 1000000));

    // Redirect to the random room
    res.redirect('/chat/'+id);
});

app.get('/chat/:id', function(req,res){

    // Render the chat.html view
    res.render('chat');
    Emitter.emit('ChatUsers');

});

// Initialize a new socket.io application, named 'chat'
var chat = io.of('/socket').on('connection', function (socket) {

    // When the client emits the 'load' event, reply with the 
    // number of people in this chat room

    socket.on('load',function(data){

        if(chat.clients(data).length === 0 ) {

            socket.emit('peopleinchat', {number: 0});
            Emitter.emit("ChatUsers");
        }
        else {

            socket.emit('peopleinchat', {
                number: 1,
                user: chat.clients(data)[0].username,
                avatar: chat.clients(data)[0].avatar,
                id: data
            });
        }

    });

// THIS IS YOUR CODE WHAT YOU WROTE FOR ME:
    socket.on('sendUsers', function (data) {

            var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'root',
          password : '',
        });
             var  DBName   = 'use ChatDB';

    connection.connect();

    connection.query(DBName);

    connection.query('SELECT * from chat', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;

      socket.emit('sendUsers', rows);

    });
    connection.end();

    });

    // When the client emits 'login', save his name and avatar,
    // and add them to the room
    socket.on('login', function(data) {

    console.log(data);

    // Use the socket object to store data. Each client gets
    // their own unique socket object

        socket.username = data.user;
        socket.room = data.id;
        socket.avatar = gravatar.url(data.avatar, {s: '140', r: 'x', d: 'mm'});

        // Tell the person what he should use for an avatar
        socket.emit('img', socket.avatar);


        // Add the client to the room
        socket.join(data.id);

        if(chat.clients(data.id).length >= 2 ) {

            console.log(data.id);

            var usernames = [],
                avatars = [];

            usernames.push(chat.clients(data.id)[0].username);
            usernames.push(chat.clients(data.id)[1].username);

            avatars.push(chat.clients(data.id)[0].avatar);
            avatars.push(chat.clients(data.id)[1].avatar);

            // Send the startChat event to all the people in the
            // room, along with a list of people that are in it.

            chat.in(data.id).emit('startChat', {
                boolean: true,
                id: data.id,
                users: usernames,
                avatars: avatars
            });
        }

    });

    // Somebody left the chat
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {

        // Notify the other person in the chat room
        // that his partner has left

        socket.broadcast.to(this.room).emit('leave', {
            boolean: true,
            room: this.room,
            user: this.username,
            avatar: this.avatar
        });

        // leave the room
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });


    // Handle the sending of messages
    socket.on('msg', function(data){

        // When the server receives a message, it sends it to the other person in the room.
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('receive', {msg: data.msg, user: data.user, img: data.img});
    });
});
};
```